# How to get an specific data from a json column in a dataframe (R)?

Tags: r, json

I am working with an dataset that contains this kind of column, that looks like a json structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jRmJ.png)

I am trying to get only the occupation, how can I access that?

I tried to replace some symbols to convert into a chr vector

data$speakers <- str_replace(data$speakers, "[{", "(")

---

data:

```
    structure(list(X_id = c(21L, 1L, 7L, 47L, 55L), duration = c(992L, 
957L, 1266L, 1126L, 1524L), event = c("TED2006", "TED2006", "TED2006", 
"TEDGlobal 2005", "TED2006"), likes = c("17000", "110000", "60000", 
"80000", "14000"), published_date = structure(c(1156464660, 1151367060, 
1151367060, 1158019860, 1153786260), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), related_videos = c("[\"144\",\"1282\",\"1379\",\"87\",\"2302\",\"2638\"]", 
"[\"243\",\"547\",\"2093\",\"74405\",\"64693\",\"83767\"]", "[\"1725\",\"2274\",\"172\",\"2664\",\"2464\",\"1268\"]", 
"[\"2237\",\"701\",\"1095\",\"1386\",\"76211\",\"242\"]", "[\"2228\",\"1476\",\"800\",\"2890\",\"45233\",\"2694\"]"
), speakers = c("[{\"name\":\"Mena Trott\",\"occupation\":\"Blogger; cofounder, Six Apart\"}]", 
"[{\"name\":\"Al Gore\",\"occupation\":\"Climate advocate\"}]", 
"[{\"name\":\"David Pogue\",\"occupation\":\"Technology columnist\"}]", 
"[{\"name\":\"David Deutsch\",\"occupation\":\"Physicist, author\"}]", 
"[{\"name\":\"Jehane Noujaim\",\"occupation\":\"Filmmaker\"}]"
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Just added on the post

Answer (score 0):

I got some help and it worked!

"[{"name":"Mena Trott","occupation":"Blogger; cofounder, Six Apart"}]" |>
jsonlite::fromJSON() |> as_tibble() |> select(occupation) |> as.vector()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).